# How to show what fixtures are installed when I run migrate command in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-1.6, django-fixtures

I am using Django 1.6 and South for migrations. I have one single fixture `initial_data.json`. When i run `./manage.py syncdb` I get

```
Installed 48 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

However when I run `./manage.py migrate` I get

```
Installed 96 object(s) from 2 fixture(s)
```

Looks like information doubles. How to watch what fixtures are installed exactly on migrate command? This issue is important for me because I have data duplication on fixtures load in some other place in the project and this could be the reason.

**upd** I followed the suggestion to creade data migration to load fixtures on `migrate` but the question with two migrations instead of one remained:

```
./manage.py migrate
Running migrations for hello:
 - Migrating forwards to 0007_migration_fixture.
 > hello:0007_migration_fixture
 - Migration 'hello:0007_migration_fixture' is marked for no-dry-run.
Installed 102 object(s) from 2 fixture(s)
 - Loading initial data for hello.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `initial_data` fixtures with South.  Rename `initial_data.json` to some other name and [load this fixture in the data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html):

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command("loaddata", "my_fixture.json")
```

Comment: I did as you sggested but, the question remained